# Не работает JavaScript при подключении

Tags: javascript

Есть небольшой скрипт, когда просто размещен на странице то он работает, если подключаю типа то почему то не работает...
Не подскажете в чем может быть проблема?

Подключал вот так:

```
<script src="http://mysite.com/script.js"></script>
```

Содержимое подключаемого скрипта:

```
    var hours = <?php echo date("H"); ?>;
var min = <?php echo date("i"); ?>;
var sec = <?php echo date("s"); ?>;
function display() {
sec+=1;
if (sec>=60)
{
 min+=1;
 sec=0;
}
if (min>=60)
{
 hours+=1;
 min=0;
}
if (hours>=24)
 hours=0;


if (sec<10)
  sec2display = "0"+sec;
else
  sec2display = sec;


if (min<10)
  min2display = "0"+min;
else
  min2display = min;

if (hours<10)
  hour2display = "0"+hours;
else
  hour2display = hours;

document.getElementById("time_server").innerHTML = hour2display+":"+min2display+":"+sec2display;
setTimeout("display();", 1000);
}
display();
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что мы не экстрасенсы? ;) Добавьте Ваш код к вопросу

Comment: Не правильно подключаете

Comment: Ну а как правильно его подключить то?

Comment: Не работает, в смысле время не тикает?

Comment: Да, но когда просто вставляю на страничку то все отлично работает.

Comment: Может у вас time_server не закрыт тег, и вы удаляете скрипт?

Comment: <b id="time_server">00:00:00</b> вроди все закрыто...

Comment: добавь разметку в которую подключаешь, чтобы было видно где script, где `time_server`

Comment: А хотя не надо:) ошибка в `<?php echo date("H"); ?>;` и аналогичных вызовах далее

Comment: залейте на сервер, и зайдите по прямому адресу - php-вставки исполняются?

Comment: посмотри консоль браузера, когда подключаешь отдельный файлом, она должна показать ошибку

Comment: Похоже на то что в подключаемом скрипте не срабатывает php код...

Comment: @Юрий90, ну он и не должен срабатывать, потому что файл `js` и по умолчанию это расширение не обрабатывается как php

Comment: Тогда выходит надо на всех страницах размещать код, или можно как то умнее сделать?

Comment: Вариантов море, начиная от размещения на страницах только кода который с php генерируется, заканчивая, запросом этих значений по ajax, либо вообще не используя php либо добавления в настройках сервера, что расширение `js` так же может сдержать php-код и его нужно соответствующе обрабатывать

Answer (score 1):

Ну так понятное, дело у тебя получается подстановка к переменным из PHP! Т.е. у тебя когда ты просто вставляешь скрипт в файл php конечно будет работать, потому-что в момент компиляции php подставляются данные. А когда ты скрипт подключаешь, то уже этот скрипт подгружается браузером после обработки основного php файла, получается переменные не подставляются. Да и вообще не будут подставляться, так как у тебя файл js.

Решить проблему можно так:

задать в index.php

```
<head>
<script>
var hours = <?php echo date("H"); ?>;
var min = <?php echo date("i"); ?>;
var sec = <?php echo date("s"); ?>;
</script>
<script src="http://mysite.com/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Да я уже так и понял, просто мало работал с яваскрипт раньше, вот и был в курсе на счет этого нюанса...

Comment: Бывает, сам такой... удачи с кодом..

Answer (score 0):

Поместите Ваш код в блок

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Ваш код
});
```